# Where are TYPO3 constants from constant editor stored?

Tags: typo3, constants

In `Typo3 Backend -> Template -> Constants` there is a constant editor. 

Where does TYPO3 saving the constants?


Tried an fgrep -ri for an existing pattern, in case of saving to filesystem - no matches.
Tried an MySQL search for an existing pattern, in case of saving to DB - no matches. 
 
Using V6.2 at the moment, but should be indifferent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The constants set in the constant editor are stored in TypoScript syntax in the field `constants` of the table `sys_template`.